# Jquery 1.8.3, elFinder - click on image and insert img tag in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, elfinder

I am using elFinder for my project. Everything is working well, but I need one more function. I want, when I double click image, to insert **img** tag in textarea. How can I do this. I am using standard configuration for elFinder, nothing is changed there.

Answer (score 0):

Add `getFileCallback` function to place img tag in your textarea:

```
$('#elfinder').elfinder({
    // ...
    onlyMimes: ["image"],
    getFileCallback: function(file) {
        var parent = (window != window.top) ? window.parent : window.opener;
        var textarea = window.opener.document.querySelector('#id_textarea_to_insert_img_tag');
        var startPos = textarea.selectionStart;
        var endPos = textarea.selectionEnd;
        textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0, startPos)
            + '<img src=\"' + file.url + '\" title=\"\" alt=\"\" />'
            + textarea.value.substring(endPos, textarea.value.length);
    },
}).elfinder('instance');
```